# Android TextToSpeech just spells short words instead of pronounces them

Tags: java, android, cpu-word, text-to-speech

I'm using `TextToSpeech` to read words. This code works fine for most cases:

```
public void speak(String pContent) {
    if (!isAvailable() || !isReady()) return;
    this.mEngine.speak(pContent, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
}
```

However, with words that have 3 or less characters such as `dog`, `cow` it just spells each character (d - o - g). Words like `cow milk`, it spells `cow`, then reads `milk` correctly.

Did I do something wrong?

More information: I tried PicoTTS of Android, and on Galaxy Tab, I tried Samsung TTS too, both of them have this issue.

Comment: @NickMartin Yes, the initialization must be completed successfully before isAvailable is true, and the engine can still read others long words well.

Comment: Right, you have to initialize it in order to call speak. I'm asking how you went about doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK the only way to get TTS to spell words is using all capitals. I can't see your pContent, but maybe you're feeding it COW milk?

Comment: That's right! All my data was converted to uppercase! I will try to switch them to lowercase!

Comment: Tested! Thank you very much. You deserve my bounty :)

Comment: How cool is that!! As a beginner, I was just scouting for bounties. Found this one and gave it my best shot. Glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in Spanish and English with the words dog, cow, ant and I can not find the problem you are reporting. It is likely that you're missing something in the code. Use the example below, and indicates whether the problem was solved.

I hope it was useful.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TextToSpeechActivity.html

Comment: That's strange. I followed that tutorial, and I encounter the problem!